# Create custom plugin joomla with custom ordering on install

Tags: joomla

Is the a trick to set my custom plugin to load the final plugin in joomla?

I want to set order on install and not after.

Is s there a custom params to set in xml like `order="xxx"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer by adding in the xml file

```
<scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>
```

And in the script file

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

/**
 * Script file of yourplugin component.
 */
class plgSystemyourplginInstallerScript
{
    /**
     * method to run after an install/update/uninstall method.
     */
    public function postflight($type, $parent)
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        $fields = array(
            $db->quoteName('ordering').' = '.(int) 999,
        );

        $conditions = array(
            $db->quoteName('element').' = '.$db->quote('wraprotect'),
            $db->quoteName('type').' = '.$db->quote('plugin'),
        );

        $query->update($db->quoteName('#__extensions'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $db->execute();
        // $parent is the class calling this method
        // $type is the type of change (install, update or discover_install)
    }
}
```

Don't forget to edit your plugin name
And in joomla 1.5 edit `#__extensions` to `#__plugins`
And delete the line `$db->quoteName('type').' = '.$db->quote('plugin')`